# Why doesn't execute my command in table?

Tags: tables, macros, etoolbox

I think the command `\apptocmd` from "etoolbox" package doesn't work in table. What I should to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    #1\apptocmd{\saveMyNotes}{#1}{}{}%
}
\newcommand{\saveMyNotes}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \mycmd{Hi} \\
        \mycmd{Hello}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\saveMyNotes % <--- This command doesn't execute!!!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I should use `\gappto`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    #1\gappto{\saveMyNotes}{#1}{}{}%
}
\newcommand{\saveMyNotes}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \mycmd{Hi} \\
        \mycmd{Hello}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\saveMyNotes % <--- This command doesn't execute!!!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Each cell form a group, so changes are local unless you make them explicitly global.